# no pay link in paypal when going to a paypal.me link

Tags: paypal

I am aware that PayPal provides people with paypal.me links... I won't use the example of the specific person I want to pay, but it can be anybody, so as a demonstration example, suppose I want to pay somebody e.g. one of the people google shows up

[image]

So say I go to the first one

[some paypal.me link](http://paypal.me/littlewanderers/)

All fine so far

[image]

I click next

[image]

As you can see, one can barely see the words "new card", (those being words that don't interest me), since I'm looking to pay, but I see no option to pay. zooming in and out makes no difference.  And I have the same problem in both opera and chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the button in the html,  near the element that has "new card" on it, so I can find it in the html with the help of element inspector

At the moment the workaround i'm using is to add an id attribute to the button and click the button with javascript from chrome's element inspector

[image]